# Ubuntu 9.10 Nvidia GTX 260 x64 installation

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, ubuntu-9.10

I think I tried everything I could but I still can't get my Nvidia GTX 260 to run on the newest ubuntu 9.10 x64.

Update: I was able to stop the gdm with `sudo service gdm stop`

However, after downloading the latest driver from nvdia - I am told that my video card is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to, in that when I added 4GB to my laptop, the BIOS was telling the nvidia to use memory within the new 4GB range and not move passed to another location.. so I had to alter the kernel source.. more information can be found here. [link text](http://www.codingfriends.com/index.php/2010/01/07/bar-15-bar-1-no-parent-nvidia-graphics-card-does-not-work/)

In essence I had to stop any memory requester within a set range and more the nvidia new request to the new place.

If you want any help just say, if this is the case ?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. When I try to stop gdm I get this:

Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service anacron start

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility